# Android Null Object Reference in Base Adapter

Tags: android, arraylist, baseadapter

I am using a base adapter and filling various components of each list item with the corresponding elements of different array lists. I am using the following code :

```
public class OfflineAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

static Context context;
static int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<String> qid = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> author = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> vote = new ArrayList<String>();

public OfflineAdapter(Context c,int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<String> qid,ArrayList<String> author,ArrayList<String> title,ArrayList<String> vote)
{

    //super(c,layoutResourceId,qid,author,title,vote);
    this.context = c;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.qid = qid;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.vote = vote;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 20;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return qid.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    QuestionHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new QuestionHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.questionTitle);
        holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.questionAuthor);
        holder.txtTitle3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.questionVotes);
        holder.txtTitle4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.questionID);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (QuestionHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    //Question hold = data[position];
    //if(hold!=null) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title.get(position)));
        holder.txtTitle2.setText(author.get(position));
        holder.txtTitle3.setText(vote.get(position));
        holder.txtTitle4.setText(qid.get(position));
    //}
    return row;
}

static class QuestionHolder
{
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtTitle2;
    TextView txtTitle3;
    TextView txtTitle4;
}
```

But I am getting the following error :

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

on this line :

```
            holder.txtTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title.get(position)));
```

What could be the reason ?
I have initialised all the array lists and none of them are null.

Thanks !

Comment: You should have to used the qid.size() as return of getCount() method.

Comment: How do you call this adapter? Can you post that code and please see if the `ArrayList title` have value? Because as your exception says your `title list` dont have any valuse.

Comment: Offtopic: you might not have any problems here, but whenever I see 'static Context context' I know it's asking for trouble.

Comment: Make sure that you don't pass a null `title` object when you create your adapter. And for best practice, it's better to change your code with single object instead of 4 lists (like "hrskrs" answer).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, for a clean code and better programming practice, instead of  creating **4 lists of strings** as you did:

```
ArrayList<String> qid = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> author = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> vote = new ArrayList<String>();
```

create an `Object` with those **4 parameters(qid, author, title, vote)**

```
public class YourObject implements Serializable{
public String qid;
public String author;
public String title;
public String vote;
}
```

and pass a *single list* of that object to the `adapter`;

```
ArrayList<YourObject> objList = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
```

Then on `getCount()` method return `objList.size()`

Comment: I would like to only get the list to only have the first 20 elements. Which is why I have returned 20 in getCount(). Is that the correct way ?

Comment: Then create a `tmpList`, filter 20 items and add those to that list.Then send to the `adapter`. You have to read firstly how the `adapter` works

Comment: It will, but it is not a good practice to make it static like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized all the ArrayLists but then you don't use them, you use whatever gets passed in the constructor. The title list will most likely be null because you pass a null in the constructor. Check how the constructor of you adapter is called and which references are passed.